# Stochastic integral representation of $F(T-s,X_s)$-type equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, mathematics

For $T\in R$ given and fixed consider:
$$
{\rm d}F(T-t,X_t)=g(T-t,X_t)\,{\rm d}W_t.
$$
where $g(t,x)$ is a given functions and $X_t$ is a given process driven by a brownian motion ($dX_t=(...)dt+(...)dW_t$). **How does the stochastic integral representation of $F$ look like?**

Are any of these two representations correct?

$$F(T-t,X_t)=F(T-0,X_0)+\int^t_0g(T-u)dW_u (1)$$
$$F(T-t,X_t)=F(T-0,X_0)+\int^{T-t}_0g(T-u,X)dW_u (2)$$

Comment: I think the 2nd representation is correct.